# Remotely run Jenkins job behind Google IAP Proxy (JWT Auth)

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, curl

I have a machine with Jenkins set up in GCP behind an IAP Proxy. I am using the JWT-Auth plugin for Jenkins authentication.

I would now like to call a build job from another machine in GCP. Test script:

```
CLIENT_ID="xxx"
EMAIL="yyy"
URL="zzz"

IAP_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences "${CLIENT_ID}" --token-format "full")

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" $URL
```

1. I successfully retrieve the JWT token for the account
2. I can "GET" the home page - response 200.

However, when I want to POST and change my curl to build a job I get this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" "$URL/job/abcd/build"

403 No valid crumb was included in the request
```

I try to include crumb in that way:

```
JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" "${URL}/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)" )

curl -X POST -H "${JENKINS_CRUMB}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" "${URL}/job/abc/build"
```

I Enable Proxy Compability in CSRF Protection, I'm trying to use token API instead of crumb but with no luck, same error.

**Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request**

Jenkins log:

```
    Found invalid crumb $CRUMB_CHAIN. 
If you are calling this URL with a script, please use the API Token instead. 
More information: https://www.jenkins.io/redirect/crumb-cannot-be-used-for-script
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out my problem, I couldn't pass proxy-authorization to jenkins. I finally used this doc: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/#SECURITY-626 . After installing the plugin and disabling session ID checking, I can use curl along with the passed crumb.

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,%22:%22,//crumb)")

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${IAP_TOKEN}" -H "${CRUMB}" "$JENKINS_URL/job/Phone-number-reset/build?delay=0sec"
```